# How to see, in the news feed, all the entrances posted in specific Facebook group

Tags: facebook

Facebook follows some kind of criteria to show some post and hide others.

I'd like to force Facebook to show all the posts posted in a specific group I'm interested.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy (surprisingly I didn't see it yesterday).

Open the group. At the upper-right corner, click on Notifications. Then, select All notifications.

[image: screenshot]